# eclipse RCP p2 UpdateOperation ProvisioningJob null

Tags: eclipse, rcp, p2

I am trying to implement an RCP project with p2 update.
When try to get ProvisioningJob returns null.

```java
final ProvisioningSession session = new ProvisioningSession(agent);
final UpdateOperation operation = new UpdateOperation(session);
configureUpdate(operation);
//some other code
final ProvisioningJob provisioningJob = operation.getProvisioningJob(monitor);
```

the monitor is a NullProgressMonitor (I've tried to configure another with Dependency Injection, but not work).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for `UpdateOperation` says you need to resolve the update before getting the provisioning job:

```java
UpdateOperation op = new UpdateOperation(session);
IStatus result = op.resolveModal(monitor);
if (result.isOK()) {
  op.getProvisioningJob(monitor).schedule();
}
```

(not sure exactly what this does as I don't use p2!)

Comment: sorry, i just forgot put this part here, but i have a call to resolveModal, such as _final IStatus status = operation.resolveModal(monitor);_

Comment: Is the status OK? getProvisioningJob returns null if the status was Cancel or Error.